# Box2dWeb - Current Vertices of a Polygon?

Tags: box2d

I'm trying to develop a game where I need to find the current vertices of a Polygon. When I try to get vertices using this method:

```
fixture.GetShape().GetVertices()
```

I get the original vertices and NOT the current vertices. Is there any workaround?

Comment: You will have to transform the original vertices by the current position and angle of the body. Doesn't the box2dweb have a debug draw that you could look at to see how they did it?

Comment: I solved the problem. Went through Box2d flash manual and used GetWorldPoint().